# Accessing data file on Android 9 Internal Memoy

Tags: java, android

I had developed a small application on Android 4.5, 5 years ago.
This application is for searching on .csv files (text files) if a certain item was on the file.
The data .csv files were on a smartcard (external memory)
This was working.
Today I changed of mobile and run on Android 9.0. 
I **changed** my application only to run on internal memory in "/storage/emulated/0/Download/".
But I get the following message:
either in  several internal directories
**java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/books.csv (Permission denied)**
or
**java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/books.csv (Permission denied)**

The file is present, I can open it on the mobile with a simple text editor.
I have searched how to read in internal storage, but not found a solution.
Can you help.
Thank you

Comment: Can you get permission from user side read write external file ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to check for runtime permission

```
private static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 0;

int permissionCheckStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
if (permissionCheckStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
        && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            REQUEST_PERMISSION);

    return;
}
```

and add permission in your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I don't understand the need to acces to EXTERNAL storage (which was in my program), as I want to read INTERNAL storage ?

Comment: @user1640478  you get  `/storage/emulated/0/` as the path of  EXTERNAL storage as you want in question.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running Android 6.0 Marshmallow (API 23) or later. If this is the case, you must implement runtime permissions before you try to read/write external storage.

Comment: Yes it is said in my question. I use Android 9

Comment: I have also authozised my application in the application zone of android parameters and some dir like download are accessible.